# In Play Framework, how to I optimize my Require.js files?

Tags: requirejs, playframework-2.1

I'm using Play Framework 2.1, its a web app with `jquery bootstrap underscore backbone` app,

can I use Node.js to run the r.js optimizer?

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Add this to your project settings:

```
requireNativePath := Some("r.js"),
requireJsShim += "shim.js"
```

Then create the shim.js file with your require js configuration settings:

```
app/assets/javascripts/shim.coffee
```

Example optimization could be something along the lines of uglify, uglify2, closure, and closure.keepLines.

```
require.config
  optimize: "uglify2"
```

Use this as a reference: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js and https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js.

You can either install requirejs globally or locally through node. Assuming it's global the native path above should be fine. If it's installed locally you can add the local bin path to your user $PATH and it should work. Either way the optimization should run through node. This should speed up js compilation times of your build tremendously.